# Firefox Does Not Allow Calling 2dContext.getImageData

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to process a video on canvas and output it on another canvas, following this article [Real-Time Video Processing with JavaScript](https://redstapler.co/realtime-video-processing-javascript-tutorial/). It basically replaces the video's green background with firework background from another video. Each time I call context.getImageData to extract image data for a frame, I face this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.

In Chrome, the error is like:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on
> 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by
> cross-origin data

I'm running the code locally with no server, so I don't think there is any CORS issue in the code.

Here's my (rather, the original post owner's) complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Video Processing</title>

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <video id="video" width="800" src="video2.mp4" muted autoplay loop></video>
        <canvas id="output-canvas" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

    <script>
let video,c1,ctx1,c_tmp,ctx_tmp; 
video2 = document.createElement('video');
video2.src = "fire.mp4";
video2.muted = true;
video2.autoplay = true;

function init() {
  video = document.getElementById('video');

  c1 = document.getElementById('output-canvas');
  ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d');

  c_tmp = document.createElement('canvas');
  c_tmp.setAttribute('width', 800);
  c_tmp.setAttribute('height', 450);
  ctx_tmp = c_tmp.getContext('2d');

  video.addEventListener('play', computeFrame );
}

function computeFrame() {
    ctx_tmp.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth , video.videoHeight );
    let frame = ctx_tmp.getImageData(0, 0, video.videoWidth , video.videoHeight);

    
    ctx_tmp.drawImage(vidoe2, 0,0, video2.videoWidth, video2.videoHeight);
    let frame2 = ctx_tmp.getImageData(0,0, video2.videoWidth, video2.videoHeight);

    for (let i = 0; i < frame.data.length /4; i++) {
        let r = frame.data[i * 4 + 0];
        let g = frame.data[i * 4 + 1];
        let b = frame.data[i * 4 + 2];               
    
          if (r > 70 && r < 160 && g > 95 && g < 220 && b > 25 && b < 150) 
          {  
              frame.data[i * 4 + 0] = frame2.data[i * 4 + 0];
              frame.data[i * 4 + 1] = frame2.data[i * 4 + 1];
              frame.data[i * 4 + 2] = frame2.data[i * 4 + 2];
          }        
        

    }

    ctx1.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
    setTimeout(computeFrame, 0);



}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    init();
  });


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Firefox version is 89.0.2 on Linux. Interestingly, seems like the code works on localhost server.
Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: But, I didn't taint anything :(

Comment: `seems like the code works on localhost server` is "secure" .... https is secure .... http is not - maybe that's the issue?

Comment: No, localhost is working and is not https.

Comment: well, that is odd

Comment: I get no errors on both Chrome and Firefox using HTTPS, though it does slow down Firefox a fair bit. There is also a typo in your code, "vidoe2" instead of "video2", but that is unrelated to your issue. I would keep in mind that most browsers treat {http://}example.com and {https://}example.com as different origins. Just ensure that all network requests are using HTTPS in the network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: Also, the sources of the videos must be on the same domain and subdomain etc. unless the server explicitly allows cross origin requests. So you must either host the video on the same server as the HTML page or set a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the other server which serves the videos.

Comment: When you say "I'm running the code locally with no server" you mean that it's using the "file://" URI scheme right? That will cause numerous issues with browsers. You must serve both the page and videos with either HTTPS or HTTP. With "file://" I get the same errors you describe. This is because all requests using "file://" are treated as cross origin.

Comment: @65536 yes I mean using the file scheme. As it seems to work over http and https. But, what's the deal? I don't have any script to run to need a server. Not sure why it might make a difference.

Comment: @codezombie All requests on the file URI scheme are treated as cross origin on purpose. It's done for security reasons so that code can't access other files on your computer. For example if you open an HTML file in the browser located at file://Users/admin/Desktop/app.html if they were not treated as cross origin requests, the code could request file://Users/admin/Documents/private.pdf and send it to an attacker. The error is only caused because when you access the content, it would be able to be sent to an attacker. Web servers limit what files can be accessed on the computer that it runs on.

Comment: @65536 Thank you it's very interesting to know about cross-origin access in this context. Basically what i understand from this is that every file accessed with file schema is considered a different origin. Or maybe its path excluding file name is considered so?

Comment: @codezombie Yes, all files accessed with the file scheme are effectively treated as being from different origins, it doesn't matter whether the path before the file name is the same or not.